# MySQL UPDATE query syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

I have this simple code and for some reason it doesn't work.

```
$query_2 = mysql_query("UPDATE movimenti
                        SET
                        movimenti.id_dentista = $hidden_id_dottore,
                        movimenti.id_trattamento = $hidden_id_tratt,
                        movimenti.id_cliente = $hidden_id_paz,
                        movimenti.movimenti = $movimento
                        WHERE movimenti.id = $id")
                        or die(mysql_error());
```

this is the error about the query:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
 for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE movimenti.id = '79'' at line 7"

Comment: Are any of your data strings?

Comment: no, only numbers (int) and $movimento is a decimal type

Comment: Could you echo the string you're executing and share the result please?

Comment: can you show how did you set `$id` ?

Comment: I haven't seen any other db related questions in your history; I take it you're new to this? If so, a common mistake is that people mix MySQL APIs. Which one are you using, `mysql_`? `mysqli_`? PDO? I can't see this failing other than what's contained in `movimenti.movimenti = $movimento` - do a var_dump on that and post how your variables are assigned as.

Comment: if id is an integer, it shouldn't be in quotes as the error says ('79')

Comment: id is an integer and movimento is a decimal(10,2) and it is very strange as error as I used this type of query a lot of times..

i use mysql query not mysqli

Comment: nonetheless, the problem's coming from what's being assigned/pulled in from `$movimento`. next to impossible to answer until we know where that is coming from and how. plus, you do have a column named `movimenti.movimenti` right? same as your table name? make sure there's a space between `$movimento` and `WHERE`. Hard to say if that's your actual code and not just formatted for Stack.

Comment: No answer here, but please, please make the internet a bit safer and don't use mysql-extension, use PDO or mysqli! Thank you!

Comment: *"ok the variable is empty.. now i have clue.. thanks"* - this question could have easily been avoided by checking/echoing what's being passed, before posting. I asked you 11 mins prior to this. *" I can't see this failing other than what's contained in movimenti.movimenti = $movimento - do a var_dump on that and post how your variables are assigned as"*

Comment: sorry I haven't understood.. my fault..

Comment: so where are we with the question, did you solve it yet? plus, I have a strange feeling that you're using JS with this, seeing your other questions. If this has been solved, let the community know, otherwise your question is still considered as open. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: thanks it is solved! i solved it right now!

Comment: You're welcome but I think you may have accepted the wrong answer. This http://stackoverflow.com/a/31808417/ is the one I gave you. I think it 'answers' the question. You'd just be sending out the wrong message to the community here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So try to debug your variables

```
$sql = "UPDATE movimenti
        SET
        movimenti.id_dentista = $hidden_id_dottore,
        movimenti.id_trattamento = $hidden_id_tratt,
        movimenti.id_cliente = $hidden_id_paz,
        movimenti.movimenti = $movimento
        WHERE movimenti.id = '.$id.'";
echo '<pre>'.$sql.'</pre>';
```

We don't know what you have assigned to variables, show to us, remember about quotes

Comment: UPDATE movimenti
        SET
        movimenti.id_dentista = 1,
        movimenti.id_trattamento = 46,
        movimenti.id_cliente = 3,
        movimenti.movimenti = 
        WHERE movimenti.id = '.55.'

ok the variable is empty.. now i have clue.. thanks

Comment: Now it is obvious what the problem is. There is nothing between = and WHERE

Answer (score 3):

Seeing in comments pulled from it and from another answer that there is nothing being passed for the `$movimento` variable:

> *"UPDATE movimenti SET movimenti.id_dentista = 1, movimenti.id_trattamento = 46, movimenti.id_cliente = 3, movimenti.movimenti = WHERE movimenti.id = '.55.' ok the variable is empty.. now i have clue.. thanks"*

So it's clear; the `$movimento` variable is empty/not set somewhere and you need to find out why.

Sidenote: `WHERE movimenti.id = '.$id.'";` don't use that, there is no need for it; remove the quotes just as you have it in your original query `WHERE movimenti.id = $id`.

Use a ternary operator assignment before your query.

- **Please read the following very carefully.**

Since we don't know how/where those variables are being assigned as, or pulled from (you have been asked a few times about this but have not told us, or updated your question), am submitting the following answer.

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);  
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$movimento = "fetched value"; // this is unknown. Replace with actual.
$movimento = !empty($movimento) ? $movimento : 'The variable/value is empty, using default value';

...
// rest of your code/query
```

Sidenote: Obviously, "The variable/value is empty, using default value" is only an example in order for me to show you that this text can be replaced by a default value, in your case it would be the decimal value, rather than a string; which will throw a syntax error. Again, this is just an example of how a ternary operator works. You can leave the default value empty.

```
$movimento = !empty($movimento) ? $movimento : '';
```

More on the ternary operator can be found here:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

If as you say the `$movimento` is a decimal then your query is fine. **If** however that that variable or any variable is a string, then those need to be quoted. I.e. `'$var'` in the query.

Now, if `movimenti.movimenti = $movimento` is still causing problems, you can also try quoting it `movimenti.movimenti = '$movimento'` but to be honest, that may not make a difference, it's only a suggestion.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

You should get used to using prepared statements though and `mysql_` functions are deprecated and will be removed from future PHP releases.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement